# Can "比" go without a subject?

Tags: grammar, comparison

Take a look at this sentence.

> **比**那刘姥姥进了大观园，还要土里土气

For some reason I translate this sentence as "Compared to A, B is more ...", though this doesn't make any sense to me.

Although I found this sentence in a song (which I think could be incorrect), I'm curious if this is a correct and valid sentence. Is this a correct sentence? If it is correct, what nouns are being referred to? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense? "A" refers to the thing of "刘姥姥进大观园".

Comment: I think so, but since "比” requires two nouns to compare, what does "B" refer to? I can't find the second noun. I'm thinking "B" refers to "我". Is this correct?

Comment: Ohh, yes, the subject is missed here. If it is "我", then the whole sentence means "I'm more 土里土气 than 刘姥姥 when she entered 大观园".

Comment: Yes, that was my thinking. So, does that means the sentence is wrong?

Comment: No. The subject is just omitted, but it's still there. We can get it from the context.

Comment: So if the context is clear, like if oneself says this sentence, you can omit "我". It all makes sense now.

Comment: Yes. The subject is often omitted in spoken language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**比** (object)，还要 (adjective)] = [ more (adjective), **compare to** (object)]

- 比[那刘姥姥进了大观园]，还要[土里土气]
- 那刘姥姥进了大观园 is  the object phrase
- 土里土气 is the adjective phrase

**The subject is omitted** in this sentence, but it is there.

You have to have a subject to compare to an object: "**Subject**' (omitted) **比** [那刘姥姥进了大观园]，**还要** [土里土气]"

The subject can be a noun, or another **phrase**

Comment: That means if oneself says the sentence, you can omit the subject. Am I right?

Comment: It means 'who' or 'what' is the subject is obvious, base on the context. A sentence before this one must had indicated who or what the subject is.

Answer (score 0):

比那刘姥姥进了大观园，还要土里土气

it is correct,but is not commenly use in modern now

It is means something(A) is lower than the (B)刘姥姥进了大观园,

but the subject(A) is missing,you should fond in the context!

Comment: can you spell check your post?