# What is the meaning of "比一比" in 一件件新衣向身上比一比?

Tags: translation, meaning

Continuing from my previous [question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28307/can-%E6%AF%94-go-without-a-subject), here's another sentence I picked from a song.

> 一件件新衣向身上**比一比**。

I tried to search through [Pinpin Dictionary](http://dictionary.pinpinchinese.com/definitions/t/%E6%AF%94%E4%B8%80%E6%AF%94-biyibi), it means:

- To make a comparison
- To engage in a contest
- To compare a little

which is rather odd and not making any sense to the sentence.

I also think that "比一比" is a reduplication of "比", which could have the same meaning as "比比". I found one in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%94%E6%AF%94), it means:

- Everywhere; All over
- All the time; Again and again

which has a better translation.

To sum up, what does "比一比" mean in this sentence? Could it mean "everywhere; all over"? Or do you have any other translation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is basic grammar: search site for verb reduplication  动词的重叠(or check any grammar)

Comment: If this is the basic grammar, could you explain why "比比" means differently with "比一比"?

Comment: comment ＃１refers to 比一比 （trying on [different 新衣, and making comparisons]） as in the quoted sentence) not to 比比，(as can be looked up in grammars or previous Q&A) V reduplication 动词重叠 refers to all of the following: V+V,V一V，V了V，e.g. 看看，看一看，看了看，点点头，摇摇头，用扇子向脸上扇一扇，that does not exclude that VV for some V may have a special meaning （deserving a dictionary entry) as happens in the case of 比比 （bkrs：1) all; each one
2) incessantly; always）compare with 比比皆是 （bkrs：meet the eye everywhere; be great in number; be seen everywhere -- in abundance; can be found everywhere; one on the heels of another）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[比](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/674/) in most context means "to compare" e.g. 比大小 (compare the size)

But in the sentence, "一件件新衣向身上**比**一比" , '比' means '**to cling to** or '**lie next to**' (*in order to compare or match*)'

It is very common for a person to pick up a new clothes and  'cling' it to his body to check if the size and the style is for him

You can see it more clearly without reduplication of '比'

"把那件新衣往身上比一下, 看看大小是否适合"

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me! Especially there's a word "一件件", indicating the new clothes is more than one to compare which one is better. Thank you, marked this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here “比一比”是指一个动作。即把衣服贴在身上（对着镜子）看看，而不是试穿，动作比较随意。
“比一比”refers to an action, that is to take up a new dress and then cling it on one’s body but not trying on.It is more casual.
To have a look it is if suitble to the color, size, style etc.
另外，“一件件新衣向身上比一比”常用“往身上比一比”很少用“向”字。虽然“向”和“往”都可以指动作的方向。
Other, we prefer using “往” but “向”, although both are refering the direction of a action .

Answer (score 0):

first
看一看=看，
试一试=试，
比一比=比，
谈一谈=谈。。。
Second
In this sentence，“比” means compare the size of clothes with your shape.

Comment: I already know about the reduplication of verb, I just need to know what is the meaning in this context, which is already answered by @Tang Ho.